# Sign in is falling on capybara feature test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying to login a user with capybara.

```
FactoryGirl.create :user, email: 'testmail@example.com', password: 'testpassword', password_confirmation: 'testpassword'
  visit '/users/sign_in'

  fill_in 'user[email]', with: 'testmail@example.com'
  fill_in 'user[password]', with: 'testpassword'
  click_on 'Login'

  expect(current_path).to eq '/logedinpage'
```

and I am getting an invalid email or password error.
I can login to the page correctly when I am typing the credentials.

Comment: Are you using comfirmable?

Comment: If so... read this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Comment: if you're using devise of course... :)

Comment: I am using devise but not the confirmable module.

Comment: Hmm, strange, your code looks fine to me! Sorry, can't help you.

Comment: maybe try `click_on submit`?

Comment: Does maybe a another spec create an User with the same E-Mail address and another password. If so take a look into the [DatabaseCleaner Gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner). It cleans the database after every spec up.

Comment: I would also highly recommend you to save the created FactoryGirl instance into a instance variable (eg. `@user = FactoryGirl.create :user`). Instead of setting custom email addresses and passwords, use the attributes from the generated object. (eg. `fill_in 'user[email]', with: @user.email`). It's lot less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `expect(current_path).to eq(...)`  due to the timing issues it creates.  If you're using any driver other than racktest the click_on executes asynchronously which means the browser clicks the button and returns immediately.  This means that when you're checking the current_path the page is most likely still submitting the form and therefore hasn't actually changed the page yet.  Instead you should be using the have_current_path matcher included in Capybara 2.5+ which adds capybaras waiting behavior to the check for current_path

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/logedinpage')
```